popToRootViewController(animated: true) doesn’t animate when called from tabBarController(_:didSelect:)
I have the following code to pop back to the root view controller of a tab if the user taps on the tab while it’s already selected. While the view controllers updates, it does not animate!
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    func tabBarController(
        _ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
        didSelect viewController: UIViewController
    ) {
        if /* tab didn't change */ {
            (viewController as! UINavigationController)!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
}

However, if I write:
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    func tabBarController(
        _ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
        didSelect viewController: UIViewController
    ) {
        if /* tab didn't change */ {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(
                withTimeInterval: 1,
                repeats: false
            ) { (_) in
                (viewController as! UINavigationController)!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

This does animate a second later.
I assume something is blocking animations during a tab switch. I tried replacing the timer with in DispatchQueue.main.async which didn’t work and tried calling UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true) which also didn’t work.
Why does iOS block animations during a tab switch and how can I still play my animation?

If you have a UINavigationController as the tab's view controller, the default behavior when tapping on that (same) tab is to animate back to the root of the navigation stack. What happens if you get rid of your didSelect viewController func completely?

The issue you're experiencing arises because the didSelect method is called at a time when animations are disabled, likely due to the internal mechanics of the tab bar controller's selection change handling. To ensure that your popToRootViewController call is animated, you can defer the call to the next run loop cycle using DispatchQueue.main.async.
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Ensure this is a UINavigationController
        guard let navController = viewController as? UINavigationController else { return }

        // Check if the selected view controller is already the current view controller
        if tabBarController.selectedViewController == viewController {
            // Defer the call to the next run loop cycle
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                navController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

Explanation:

Conforming to UITabBarControllerDelegate: Ensure that your MyTabBarController conforms to UITabBarControllerDelegate and set self as the delegate in viewDidLoad.

Deferred Execution: By using DispatchQueue.main.async, the
popToRootViewController(animated:) call is deferred to the next     run loop cycle. This way, it executes after the tab bar controller has
completed its own transition animations.

Safeguard Against Non-UINavigationController: The code checks to
ensure that the viewController is actually a UINavigationController
before attempting to call popToRootViewController.


This should resolve the issue and allow the animation to run smoothly.
